# Does Windows 7 VPN push Client DNS?

Tags: vpn, dns

I'm using a VPN in conjunction with my iPad (no OpenVPN sorry!) so have just configured the Windows 7 PPTP VPN and i've got it working fine.

However what I need to know is will it force my iPad to use the global DNS settings configured in Windows, or will it use the DNS settings i've set on my iPad?

I've got unblock-us at home and would like to use it on my iPad while i'm away.  Since unblock-us uses IP addresses it wouldn't work on my iPad outside of my home network, hence the use of a VPN ;)

The only issue is I don't want to use unblock-us DNS's on my Windows box, only on my iPad

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does push client DNS   :)